# Detect Time Since Last Boot in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, boot

Is it possible to detect the time since a device was last booted in client-side JavaScript?

Comment: I doubt this is possible.

Comment: In the _browser_ - probably not.  In _node_ on a server device... _maaaaybe?_

Comment: In plain ECMAScript, no. However, implementations are free to extend the language and offer more features (e.g. features of JavaScript that provide access to language settings), but I doubt any will provide access to such low level host information.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In client-side javascript; NO.
The OS level details are not exposed to the javascript run-time in browsers

But if by client-side you mean an android application running javascript in WebView, there may be a plugin to extract the info